# mysql_fetch_assoc showing one record in a While loop

Tags: mysql, fetch

I'm trying to display all comments made in certain posting page. All variable calls work fine (including the function timeago) but it only shows the very first comment only.

```
$com_sql = "SELECT  comments.com_id,
                    comments.com_topic,
                    comments.com_user,
                    comments.com_content,
                    comments.com_date,
                    users.userid,
                    users.username,
                    users.usernombre,
                    COUNT(com_topic) AS com_top
            FROM comments
            LEFT JOIN users
            ON comments.com_user = users.userid
            WHERE com_topic = " . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "
            GROUP BY com_topic
            ORDER BY com_id DESC";

$com_result = mysql_query($com_sql);

if(!$com_result)
{echo 'The COMMENTS table could not be displayed.';}
else
{   if(mysql_num_rows($com_result) == 0){ echo 'No comments yet!';}
}

// Now I should show them one by one:
// Should $com_row be com_top??

while($com_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($com_result))
{ echo '<table width="100%" height="253" border="4">
<tr><td width="9%" rowspan="2" valign="top"><p>IMG</p>
<p>editar</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p></td><td width="63%">';

$com_user = stripslashes($com_row['username']);
$com_usernombre = stripslashes($com_row['usernombre']);
echo $com_user;
echo $com_usernombre;

echo '</td><td width="4%" height="24"><div align="right"> <p>PM</p>
</div></td><td width="24%"><div align="right">';

$referencedate = strtotime($com_row['com_date']);
$result = timeago($referencedate); 
echo 'Ago';
echo $result ;

echo '</div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="3" valign="top">';

$com_content = stripslashes($com_row['com_content']);
echo $com_content;
echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

I am using the same template in other parts of my page and they work fine :-/
What am I doing wrong? Is the COUNT fine?? Am I using the while($com_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($com_result)) correctly??
Hope you can help me :-)

THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will select one row for each distinct value of `com_topic`.  This is due to the use of `GROUP BY`.  If you omit the `GROUP BY` clause, then you should also omit the aggregate column `COUNT(com_topic) as com_top`.

Otherwise, everything else looks ok.

Comment: YAY!!! You are amazing boy! I spent the whole day trying to fix that but it took you 10 seconds to find out :-/ THANKS Lee!!